# Cannot find column in table when refreshing data

Tags: powerbi

I am rather new at PowerBI because I have mostly used other tools but I need to use them for a customer. I have this problem that I haven't been able to solve.

I have created two CSV-files using python and I save them in a specific location. I update these files every day and I have since their first creation date never changed anything. The files are ";" separated.

Now, I created a dashboard in PowerBI by first importing these files and connecting them using a common key. All the visuals work just fine. The next day, I wanted to update the data since the CSV-files on my disc had been updated with my python code.

The problem is that PowerBI will not update the tables. In fact I get the error **"Det gick inte att hitta kolumnen <namn på kolumnen> i tabellen"** which in english would be **Column  cannot be found in table**. The column is the first column in the PWBI table (since the application ordered these columns in alphabetical order).

I have tried every possible thing, from the cleansing cache memory to change the order of columns. Whatever I try fails.

[image]

In this image above it says: "Cannot find column BKVehicelID in the table" and the second error is "Update was blocked because of errors in other queries". I can, however, update the second column by itself.

I would really appreciate any help on this.